# Malicious link? Apache?

Tags: web-browser, apache, encoding, web

I've got a link from spammer, the link is very strange, but after redirects I got the web page full of ads. Here is the link(doesn't require "http://"):

> /0xD805A9E4///RLI=590-UI=273411771-OI=6313-ONI=325215-SI=0-CI=10360210-BI=0-II=1997780-IDSP=58-KLEM=11-TIE=16-IDE=11362537-MID=384-FID=57172-DIOM=0

The link is strange, but it works, is it malicious? Will this link install something on my device and what type of encription is that? Even link scanners don't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an IP address in octal format, followed by an arbitrary path, which happens to be formed of elements that look like query parameters.

You can generate octal representations of IP addresses using various online tools: [0xD83AD60E](http://0xD83AD60E) should link to Google at 216.58.214.14. They're not inherently malicious, but the fact that you received it from a spammer suggests that there is a reason they wanted you to follow it, and the page it loads may well attempt to install malware. Since you did follow it, you may already be infected, in fact.

Links don't (generally) infect computers, but the pages they link to may well do. Never follow links sent by spammers - at the very least, you verify that your email address works. At worst, you end up infected with cryptoware and lose your data.